# Accessing a method in application controller using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

All,

I'm trying to use bootstrap-navbar for a simple password verification (no username required here).

From application.html.erb:

```
   <%= form_tag "/",:controller => 'application',:action => 'tryy' do %>
        <%= label_tag "Enter password.." %>
        <%= password_field_tag "login_password" %>
        <div><%= submit_tag "Go!", :class=>'btn btn-success' %></div>
    <% end %>
```

And application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :subd?, :tryy

  def subd?
    !((request.subdomain == '') || (request.subdomain=='www'))
  end

  def tryy
    999
    puts 999
  end
end
```

the 'puts' in tryy is just to see that anything is happening using the rails server logging window.

Problem - when submitting the form nothing happens, namely no "999" print. Note there's no error message here either. I suspect the method "subd?" is not relevant to this problem, but copying application_controller.rb in its entirety, in case it is.

Any ideas regarding what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around tryy

```
:action => tryy
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to send a form to application controller. If u want to try, then create one controller and then test. You will get success in that.